# Call a controller method without loading a blank view

Tags: html, razor, model-view-controller

I'm trying to call a controller method to delete a record in my database and I am using an actionlink to do this but whenever I hit the delete button, it will delete the record in the database, but it redirects me to a blank page. What I am trying to do is have it not redirect to anything but I can't seem to get that to work.

HTML/Razor

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "DeleteRecord", new { id = item.JPAppId }, new { @class = "fa fa-trash"})
```

Controller Method

```
public void DeleteRecord(Guid id)
    {
        JPApplication jPApplication = db.JPApplications.Find(id);
        db.JPApplications.Remove(jPApplication);
        db.SaveChanges();            
    }
```

Comment: If you want to stay on the same page then use ajax to call a server method that deletes the record (and a delete action should be a POST, not a GET)

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll try and see if I can get it to work using ajax